# Problems With Hosting Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am having Problems With Launching a minecraft Server. I have tried spigot and open it with a batch file but it doesn't seem to work. I am on windows 10 the code for the batch file I am using is

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.9 -o true
PAUSE
```

And it doesn't launch the jar file it says error unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.1.8.9

Comment: what is the full path and filename of the jar file? minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar? It probably can't find the file. try to give it a full path like `C:\some\directory\minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar` or whatever

Comment: Its in the same foulder So it shouldn't matter i think but i will try anyway

Comment: stil not working

Comment: I redirected it to my desktop so it should be easy for it to find it but it stil can't find it

Comment: @MemoryPenguin's answer was basically what I was trying to say -- java is looking for a file without the jar extension because that's what you supplied. You have to provide the full pathname, even though Windows hides file extensions by default (which is stupid IMO).

Answer (score 2):

Your launch command is missing the file extension. It should look like this:

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.9.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

By default these extensions are hidden in Windows Explorer; you can turn them on (in Windows 10) by clicking on the View tab at the top of the folder and checking the box by 'File name extensions'.

[image: File name extension toggle]